how to solve the partial derivative of layernorm in neural network: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial loss}{\partial x}$
give eq as:
$$
y (loss) = \frac{x-\mathrm{E}[x]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon}} * \gamma+\beta = norm * \gamma + \beta
$$
$\gamma$ and $\beta$ are indepandant of x.
norm defined as:
$$
norm = \frac{x-\mathrm{E}[x]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon}}
$$
rstd defined as:
$$
rstd\ (reciprocal\ standard\ deviation) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon}}
$$
variance as:
$$
var = \frac{1}{N} \cdot \sum_i^N (x_i-\mathrm{E}[x])^2
$$
then how to solve the partial derivative dy/dx? name y as loss, I tried the following to get dloss/dx:
$$
\frac{\partial loss}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial loss}{\partial norm} \cdot
\frac{\partial ((x-\mathrm{E}[x]) \cdot rstd)}{\partial x}
$$
$$
dx = dnorm \cdot [\frac{\partial (x-\mathrm{E}[x])}{\partial x} \cdot
rstd + \frac{\partial rstd}{\partial x} \cdot (x-\mathrm{E}[x])]
$$
$$
dx = dnorm \cdot \left(\frac{\partial (x-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)}{\partial x} \cdot
rstd + \frac{\partial [(\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)^{-\frac{1}{2}}]}{\partial x} \cdot
(x-\mathrm{E}[x])\right)
$$
$$
= dnorm \cdot \left( (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot rstd -
\frac{1}{2} (\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot
\frac{\partial (\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)}{\partial x} \cdot
(x-\mathrm{E}[x])\right)
$$
$$
= dnorm \cdot \left( (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot rstd -
\frac{1}{2} (\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot
\frac{\partial [\frac{1}{N} \sum_i^N(x_i-\mathrm{E}[x])^2]}{\partial x} \cdot
(x-\mathrm{E}[x])\right)
$$
$$
= dnorm \cdot \left( (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot rstd -
(\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)^{-\frac{3}{2}} \cdot 
\frac{x_i - \mathrm{E}[x]}{N} \frac{\partial (x_i - \mathrm{E}[x])}{\partial x} \cdot
(x-\mathrm{E}[x])\right)
$$
$$
= dnorm \cdot \left( (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot rstd -
(\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \cdot 
\frac{x_i - \mathrm{E}[x]}{\sqrt {\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon}} \cdot
\frac{1}{N} (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot
\frac{x-\mathrm{E}[x]}{\sqrt {\operatorname{Var}[x]+\epsilon}} \right)
$$
recall the existed definitions, simplify the above eq as:
$$
dx = dnorm \cdot \left( (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot rstd -
rstd \cdot
norm \cdot
\frac{1}{N} (1-\frac{1}{N}) \cdot
norm \right)
$$
$$
= rstd \cdot
\left( (dnorm-\frac{dnorm}{N}) -
norm \cdot
\frac{1}{N} (\frac{N-1}{N}) \cdot dnorm \cdot norm \right)
$$
$$
= rstd \cdot
\left( (dnorm-\frac{dnorm}{N}) -
norm \cdot
((N-1) \cdot \frac{dnorm}{N} \cdot \frac{norm}{N} \right)
$$
however, the answer is as follows:
$$
= rstd \cdot
\left( (dnorm-\frac{dnorm}{N}) -
norm \cdot
(\frac{dnorm}{N} \cdot \frac{norm}{N} \right)
$$
with reference to pytorch autograd & llm.c project
https://github.com/karpathy/llm.c/blob/fd564f7b8aadabe53c7cf609ae4e989b2ce58ccd/doc/layernorm/layernorm.py#L30
I cannot reach to the answer by above inference, need some guidance here.
